# Account deactivated and unable to login to online banking after moving out of the USA some years ago — how do I reactivate it?

Tags: united-states, banking, online-banking

I left the USA about 6 years ago. Until some time ago, I used to be able to login to my online banking to check my balance, but I am unable to do so now. Unfortunately, they also have my US phone number as contact information. The only thing is the email id where I have received this communication.

How do I sort out this situation?

Comment: Why exactly did the bank say they were deactivating the account?

Comment: Did you call the bank and ask them for help?

Comment: "Unfortunately, they also have my US phone number as contact information" — What does this mean? How is this "unfortunate"? Is it because your US phone number has been deactivated too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the bank and ask them. We don't even know what bank this is. We could only guess at their policies.